# Group & reorder array elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I want to be regrouped. The array looks like the following.

```
$originalArray = array
(
    'APPLE' => array(
            'BASE_PRICE' => 7.5,
            'MARKUP' => 1.2
        ),

    'ORANGE' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 4
        ),

    'BANANA' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 6
        ),

    'LIME' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 8
        )

);
```

I want it reordered such that it is grouped into **BASE_PRICE** and **MARKUP** as the following.

```
$newArray = array (
    'BASE_PRICE' => array
        (
            'APPLE' => 7.5,
            'ORANGE' => 0,
            'BANANA' => 0,
            'LIME' => 0
        ),

    'MARKUP' => array
        (
            'APPLE' => 1.2,
            'ORANGE' => 6,
            'BANANA' => 4,
            'LIME' => 8
        )
);
```

How do I use loops to achieve the new array? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far I've tried the following but not getting what I expect.

```
arsort($originalArray);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post your code so we can help you understand how to make that work or where was your problem.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired array by using

```
 foreach ($originalArray as $key => $value) {
  $array1['BASE_PRICE'][$key] = $value['BASE_PRICE'];
  $array2['MARKUP'][$key] = $value['MARKUP'];
 }
 $newarray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [BASE_PRICE] => Array
        (
            [APPLE] => 7.5
            [ORANGE] => 0
            [BANANA] => 0
            [LIME] => 0
        )

    [MARKUP] => Array
        (
            [APPLE] => 1.2
            [ORANGE] => 4
            [BANANA] => 6
            [LIME] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. How do I order the array by value in descending order?

Comment: You can use `rsort()` for this

Comment: @ari1999  Please can you accept this as an answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) function :

```
function sort_array ($inputArray){
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $index => $value){
        $outputArray["BASE_PRICE"][$index] = $value["BASE_PRICE"];
        $outputArray["MARKUP"][$index] = $value["MARKUP"];
    }

    foreach ($outputArray as $value){
        asort($value);
        asort($value);
    }
    return $outputArray;
}

var_dump(sort_array($originalArray));
```

Comment: Good answer @GNassro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array-reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function by next way:

```
<?php

$originalArray = array
(
    'APPLE' => array(
            'BASE_PRICE' => 7.5,
            'MARKUP' => 1.2
        ),

    'ORANGE' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 4
        ),

    'BANANA' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 6
        ),

    'LIME' => array
        (
            'BASE_PRICE' => 0,
            'MARKUP' => 8
        )

);

$resultArray = array_reduce(
  array_keys($originalArray),
  function($accumulator, $key) use($originalArray) {
    $accumulator['BASE_PRICE'][$key]=$originalArray[$key]['BASE_PRICE'];
    $accumulator['MARKUP'][$key]=$originalArray[$key]['MARKUP'];
    return $accumulator;
  },[]
);
print_r($resultArray);
?>
```